# Insert and query MySQL point value returns ASCII

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, geospatial, geophp

I have a bit of a strange problem. I’m trying to insert MySQL point coordinates and return in PHP, but I get ASCII put instead of coordinates.

This is my SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `Grid` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cntr_point` POINT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `Grid`(cntr_point) 
VALUES(POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(49.227239 17.564932)'));
```

In PHP I have code such as this (which works for other fields):

```
$row['cntr_point']
```

But I get random ASCII character output such as this:

```
*H@v0b1@
```

When I would instead be expecting to see the coordinates I inserted. I seem to get the same even when I skip PHP and use something like SQLFiddle:

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7443da/2)

Comment: for me that generates content that looks like `00000000010100000018B0E42A169D4840C07630629F903140` for `cntr_point`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes php returns slightly different value to SQLfiddle, though neither is giving me the actual coordinates I put in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `POINT` data type contains binary data. Try [ST_AsWkt()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext) to get it displayed as text.

```sql
SELECT id, ST_AsWkt(cntr_point) FROM Grid
```

In MySQL's OpenGIS extension, geometric columns like your `POINT` column are stored in the so-called [Well-Known Binary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format) (WKB) format.  ST_AsWkt() converts WKB to [Well-Known Text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkt-format) (WKT).

The constant you use in your INSERT, `'POINT(49.227239 17.564932)'`, is an example of WKT. The [POINTFROMTEXT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_pointfromtext) function you use to load your table converts the other way.

So, yes, if you want just the long/lat data, you'll have to extract it from the WKT in your php program.  Or, you could use [GeoPHP](https://geophp.net/) to handle WKB directly if that makes sense in your app.

Comment: The AsText() function is deprecated in favor of ST_AsWkt().

Comment: That particular function `ST_AsWkt` however is not available in mySQL prior to 5.7 or so?!

Comment: Thank you for this. That seems to work. Might be a dumb question but do I then need to use PHP to strip out the surrounding Point() so I get back just the coordinates, or is there a way for the sql to return just the coordinates?

Comment: It's definitely in 5.6.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ST_AsText`:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(cntr_point) FROM Grid
```

Output: `POINT(49.227239 17.564932)`

Or you can use `ST_X` and `ST_Y` to get the coordinates:

```
SELECT id, ST_X(cntr_point), ST_Y(cntr_point) FROM Grid;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7443da/11)

Comment: Thank you for the help. As my MySQL version supports aswkt I will use that but still helpful